# The best way to make a data accessible in all actions and controllers in Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a custom identity class

```cs
public class MyIdentityUser : IdentityUser
{
    public long? DealerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Dealer Dealer { get; set; }
}
```

almost in all actions I need to access the `DealerId`

what is the best way to make the `DealerId` accessible in all of my controllers and actions?

some options could be:

1- using middleware and load the `DealerId` from database and add it to the `context.items`

2- loading user data using `UserManager<MyIdentityUser>` in all controllers' constructors

If using the middleware is a good solution, is there any simpler way than adding `DealerId` to the `context.items`?

For example, Is there any way to make the `DealerId` accessible through something like `HttpContext.User.DealerId`?

Comment: create a base controller that has `DealerId` defined in it, then let all your controllers inherit from that base controller

Comment: Thank you @LazZiya, I've done the same. and I think It's better than using context.items